# The credits that can be entered are 0,20,40,60 How to print out of range when a user doesnt input a value in the range

Tags: python, function, range

The program should display ‘Out of range’ if credits entered are not in the range 0, 20, 40,
60, 80, 100 and 120. There are 28 outcomes. user will input credits to pass, fail ,defer

```
range_of_credits = [0,20,40,60,80,100,120]

def credit_input(number_of_credits,error_message = 'Integer required'):
    while True:
        try:
            credit= int(input(number_of_credits))#
        except ValueError:
            print(error_message)
            continue
        
        break
    return credit

while True:
    credits_to_pass= credit_input('Enter the number of credits to pass:')
    credits_to_defer= credit_input('Enter the number of credits to Defer:')
    credits_to_fail= credit_input('Enter the number of credits to fail:')
   

    if credits_to_pass == 120:
        print('Progress')
    elif credits_to_pass == 100:
        print('Progress(module trailer)')
    elif credits_to_pass == 80 or credits_to_pass == 60 or credits_to_fail == 60 or credits_to_pass == 40\
    or credits_to_defer ==120 or credits_to_defer ==100 or credits_to_defer==80 or credits_to_defer==60:
        print('Do not progress - module retriever')
    elif credits_to_fail == 80 or credits_to_fail == 100 or credits_to_fail == 120 or credits_to_pass == 0 or credits_to_pass == 20:
        print('Exclude')

    
credit_input(credits_to_pass,credits_to_defer,credits_to_fail)
```

Comment: `if credits_to_pass not in range_of_credits:`

Comment: When should it display 'Out of range'? Input on pass, defer or fail? Anyways, you can just have a new check `if credits_to_pass not in range_of_credits: print('Out of range');break`

Comment: It should display out of range on input on pass, fail and defer. my question is how to write that code.

Comment: The question specifics the range, so we need to store it in a list